# How to make a simple Wizard of Oz web app for user research

Tags: web-applications, user-experience

I would like to do a wizard of Oz UX study where it works like this. Participant and researcher would be remote (not in the same room).

1. participant can open a web app on their phone.
2. researcher controls the state of the webapp on their side - The visuals and frames that the participant sees change based on the researcher clicking a button and progressing the app in real-time based on the participant's reaction

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

I'm thinking a web app with two tabs. One with the researcher's view, and one with the participant's view. The researcher has controls to modify the participant's view.

Ideas appreciated, especially if there is anything out of the box or on GitHub that can help expedite this process

Thanks!